# Snap UVs according to the polygon's vertex positions

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I want to write a geometry node graph that allows me to quickly draft a game map with grass and cliffs.
I have successfully separated the grass (Normal facing up) from the cliffs (Normal facing X(-)/Y(-)).
My next step is to generate the UVs for the Cliff polygons. Let me visualize this:
[image]

Is there a **quick** way to decide which UV correspondends to which corner of the polygon?
The resulting geometry node graph is supposed to automate the UVing.
It is important for me that each polygon spans the 0-1 UV range only, because each polygon will receive a unique texture later depending on which polygon has grass at the top/bottom.

Edit:
The polygons are not strictly straight and can be non-planar.

Edit2: In simple terms:
Regardless of orientation or form of the quad polygon, the topleft most corner should be UV (0,0), the bottom rightmost corner should be UV(1,1)

Edit3:

here is a manually uv mapped object (cliff texture only), how it should look like with Geometry Nodes
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Based on normals assign to each corner based on being a smaller x/y/z than the face center or larger.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! It works perfectly for rectangular shapes!
However, it doesn't work properly for trapezoidal or rhomboids.
https://i.imgur.com/bDCQY9R.png Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: I guess the solution would be to bring all Face Corners into a reference frame of the face (subtract position and invert normal rotation?) and compare the coordinates of all face corners with each other?

Comment: @Raildex Maybe instead assign <0, 0>, <0, 1>, <1, 1> and <1, 0> coordinates based on face corner index in face…

Comment: I already thought about it, but the order of face corners is not uniform - the "top left" is not always at index 0 .